# Why is this function being called inside conditional not working?

Tags: javascript

Why is `samSays` not working inside the function even though the function is returning?

```js
function drivinSchool() {

  var samSays = samSaysf();

  if(samSaysf === "hi there"){
    return "talks while driving"
  }
  else{
    return "doesn't talk only drives"
  }
}

function samSaysf() {
  return "hi there"
}

console.log(drivinSchool());
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? The code doesn't do anything observable.

Comment: what is the function returning?

Comment: A function isn't a string, so they don't strictly equal each other. You probably mean to do: `samSays === "hi there"` to compare the variable instead of the function.

Comment: The variable is called `samSays`, the function is called `samSaysf` and will never strictly equal the string `"hi there"`

Comment: if I console.log then it is in else. Not in the condition meets `samSaysf === "hi there"`

Comment: @Deke — "if I console.log " — So show us that in a [mcve]. (Also log `samSaysf` to see if it has the value you expect)

Comment: you can console.log just after the samSaysf() function call and see what you have got.

Comment: @Quentin This question is a MVC, what do you think is missing in terms of code? I went ahead and put it into a snippet. Although I think the main problem is OP isn't explaining the issue clearly in the question, but it seems clear enough that this issues is due to a typo.

Comment: You are comparing the function not the assignment. That's why you are getting a wrong result.